# modifying length of string so certain strings within it count as 1

Tags: php

Can't seem to figure out how to do this one.  Given a string I want to return the length of that string... simple enough, but I also want an array of 'search' strings within it to only count as one.

```
$string = 'this is [Enter]a test example of [Enter]something.';

//this can contain any number of different strings
$replace = array(
    '[Alt]',
    '[Backspace]',
    '[Ctrl]',
    '[Del]',
    '[Down]',
    '[End]',
    '[Enter]'
);
```

expected output for the above would be :

```
$string = 'this is [Enter]a test example of [Enter]something.';

// would be 50
$norm_length = strlen($string);

//where all [x]'s in above array count as 1
$length = 38;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple replace every of your keywords with a character of length one:

```
$string = 'this is [Enter]a test example of [Enter]something.';

//this can contain any number of different strings
$replace = array(
    '[Alt]',
    '[Backspace]',
    '[Ctrl]',
    '[Del]',
    '[Down]',
    '[End]',
    '[Enter]'
);

echo strlen(str_replace($replace, "_", $string));
```

(`str_replace` takes an array as search - no need for regex)

Comment: So far this seems like the best solution, but would require a copy of the original $string as I still would need the original data.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex to replace any `[*]` with a space.

```
$replace = array(
    '/\[Alt\]/',
    '/\[Backspace\]/',
    '/\[Ctrl\]/',
    '/\[Del\]/',
    '/\[Down\]/',
    '/\[End\]/',
    '/\[Enter\]/',
);
$string = preg_replace($replace, ' ', $string);
echo strlen($string);
```

Comment: this replaces *more* than the desired keywords.

Comment: Indeed, if the OP wants only the words contained in `$replace` to be replaced, he could use your answer or replace the first argument of preg_replace with the array after escaping the `[` and `]` chars.

Comment: He clearly stated *but I also want an array of 'search' strings within it to only count as one*

Comment: Updated the answer now to fit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

From your question I think you're asking for a string's characters to be counted but remove the search "term" (words surrounded by square brackets) and count those as 1. Thus giving the character count and adding one for each search term found.

```
$string = 'this is [Enter]a test example of [Enter]something.';
$originalLength = strlen($string);

echo 'The original length is: ' . $originalLength . '<br />';

//this can contain any number of different strings
$replace = array(
    '[Alt]',
    '[Backspace]',
    '[Ctrl]',
    '[Del]',
    '[Down]',
    '[End]',
    '[Enter]'
);

preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]+)\]/", $string, $searchterms);

echo 'Found:';

var_dump($searchterms[0]);

$newLength = $originalLength;

foreach($searchterms[0] as $term) {
    var_dump(strlen($term));
    $newLength = $newLength - strlen($term) + 1;
}

echo 'New length (without brackets) is';

var_dump($newLength);
```

Comment: It does also count `[foobar]` as `1`, even if its not part of `$replace`.

Comment: @dognose It does. "but I also want an array of 'search' strings". I take that as any "search string" can be defined within that Array. "//this can contain any number of different strings"

Comment: Sure any string CAN be member of the array. But your code affects *any* string inside `[]` no matter if its provided in the array or not. You can delete the array and your code behaves equal.